# Github-Action : Set Job environment only when condition true

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to set the "environment" of a job only if a defined condition is true ? So for example only if it was passed as INPUT ?

```
jobs:
  test_workflow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: EXAMPLE <-- This one
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

My use case: Im using a reusable_workflow and i only want to add the environment if it was passed to the workflow.
**environment** does not accept null/false but only string or object.

Would it work to set the default of the input to an empty string and to "example" in the other call ? What is the consequence of setting it to an empty string ?

Ref : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-environments-for-jobs

Comment: Have you tried setting it to an empty string? That you should be able to already answer (and please edit it in as a clarification to your question, I think this is interesting). And using a different value conditionally could be achieved with expressions IIRC.

Comment: It works with empty string! I added the solution as comment but can not accept it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It is possible to set the ENVIRONMENT to an empty string and it will be treated like its not set.
So i defined my INPUT with the empty string default and only pass a value if needed!.

```
      ENVIRONMENT:
        type: string
        default: ""
```

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me. +1 and you can accept it later, just don't forget to do so to mark the question as answered.